# GWT (Eclipse): 2 modules (2 entry points) + 2 HTML pages => LoginService possible for both HTML pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, entry-point

I am a newbie to GWT and at the moment I have the problem that I created two modules (see appendix 1/2) with two entry point classes in my project. So I made two run configurations (see appendix 5/6) in Eclipse to either address the HTML page for module one (It_projekt.html) or the HTML page for module two (Reportgenerator.html). For authentication purposes, I added a LoginService class.

But now, when I start the HTML page for my second module (reportgenerator.gwt.xml) in the browser, there will be no login screen. On the other hand, when I start the HTML page for module one (It_projekt.gwt.xml) in the browser, there will appear a login screen.

So my question is: how can I make it possible (if it's possible) to have one LoginService and two HTML pages, where I as a user have to login at It_projekt.html and also Reportgenerator.html (condition: it has to be two modules with two entry point classes)? Is it maybe only possible with two different LoginService classes?

For test purposes, I added a variant of the LoginService class (as you can see in the web.xml). But the second LoginService idea didn't work either. And there is definitely some code in "onModuleLoad()" in the entry point class of the second module (reportgenerator.gwt.xml).

Maybe it might depend on a small detail, but I am unable to see it at the moment. I appended all necessary resources that I could think of. Please help me!

**Appendixes:**
1) It_projekt.gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='it_projekt'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.logging.Logging'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='de.hdm.team7.client.It_projekt'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

2) reportgenerator.gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='reportgenerator'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.logging.Logging' />

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

    <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <entry-point class="de.hdm.team7.client.Reportgenerator"></entry-point>

    <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
    <add-linker name="xsiframe" />

</module>
```

3) web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Stuecklistenverwaltung</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.team7.server.StuecklistenVerwaltungImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Stuecklistenverwaltung</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/it_projekt/stuecklistenverwaltung</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Reportgenerator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.team7.server.ReportGeneratorImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Reportgenerator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/it_projekt/reportgenerator</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.team7.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/it_projekt/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServiceReports</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.team7.server.LoginServiceReportsImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServiceReports</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/reportgenerator/loginreports</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>It_projekt.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

4) LoginService.java:

```
package de.hdm.team7.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("login")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {
//  String login(User user);
    public LoginInfo login(String requestUri);
}// end interface
```

5) Run configuration:

```
It_projekt.html
-superDevMode -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl It_projekt.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort auto -port auto -war C:\Users\dev\git\it-projekt\it-projekt\war de.hdm.team7.It_projekt de.hdm.team7.reportgenerator
```

6) Run configuration:

```
Reportgenerator.html
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl Reportgenerator.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -superDevMode -war C:\Users\dev\git\it-projekt\it-projekt\war de.hdm.team7.reportgenerator de.hdm.team7.It_projekt
```